# How to use select names dialog with VBA for send Email for Recipients more than one?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm create small VBA script for send Email with VBA.I'm create Dialog box for identify Recipients.It work well but it can get one Recipient.Like this :

[image]

This's my output.It show only one last Recipient.

[image]

This's my Code:

```
Sub cc_BCC()
Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Set oMsg = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim oDialog As Outlook.SelectNamesDialog
Set oDialog = Outlook.Application.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog
Dim oAL As Outlook.AddressList
Dim oContacts As Outlook.Folder
Dim cEI As String
Dim c As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim olRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Set oContacts = _
Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
For Each oAL In Outlook.Application.Session.AddressLists
If oAL.AddressListType = olOutlookAddressList Then
If oAL.GetContactsFolder.EntryID = _
oContacts.EntryID Then
Exit For
End If
End If
Next
With oDialog
.Caption = "Select Customer Contact"
.ToLabel = "Customer C&ontact"
.NumberOfRecipientSelectors = olShowTo
.InitialAddressList = oAL
.AllowMultipleSelection = True
.Recipients = oMsg.Recipients
If .Display Then
'Recipients Resolved
For Each olRecipient In .Recipients
cEI = olRecipient.EntryID 'entry id of selected contact
Set c = Outlook.Application.Session.GetAddressEntryFromID(cEI)

Worksheets("Dialog").Range("A15") = c.GetContact.FirstName & " " & c.GetContact.LastName

Next
End If
End With
End Sub
```

And I need this output.Like this:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why the hard-coded `Worksheets("Dialog").Range("A15")` - that's overwriting the same cell every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do not hardcode the cell name ("A15"). Secondly, do not call `GetAddressEntryFromID` - just use `Recipient.AddressEntry`. Thirdly, do not assume `GetContact` will return a non-null value, it only works if the item comes from your Contacts folder, it will not work for the GAL entries.

```
For i = 1 to .Recipients.Count
  set olRecipient = .Recipients(i)
  Worksheets("Dialog").Range("A" & i) = olRecipient.name
Next
```

Comment: @Dear Dmitry Streblechenko
I got it!.Thank you so much.